# iOS webview changing session on history navigation

Tags: java, iphone, ios, uiwebview, session-variables

I am currently loading a URL on my iOS app's UIWebView component and POSTing some data at the same time. After progressing through a few pages on the webview, the user has the option of navigating back on the webview.

The problem:
If we try navigating back (history -2) on this webview with

```
    if ([webView canGoBack]) {
       [webView goBack];
    }
```

the session (on the webapp side) is changing to a new one and in the process, the session variables are getting lost.

NOTE: history -1 navigation is cached and hence session prevails.

Can anyone suggest the right way to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add two UIButton in your view and set  add target method.

```
__weak IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_Back;
__weak  IBOutlet UIButton *btn_Forward;

[btn_Back addTarget: webView
                     action:@selector(goBack)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[btn_Forward addTarget: webView
                        action:@selector(goForward) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: kalpesh and Jitendra: Thanks for the reply.

 I already have the buttons in place and they are targeted to the goBack method. The actual issue is when the user tries to go back (twice - hitory -2), the session in my webapp is changed and hence the session is lost. NOTE: this is a hybrid app with UIwebview hitting a Java Webapp.